# gmaps4rails without asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, gmaps4rails

I'm using Rails 3.2.3 and Ruby 1.9.3 along with the latest version of gmaps4rails. I am unable for the life of me to get a map to display. I keep getting JS errors stating gmap is not defined. I've followed the gmaps4rails documentation to no avail.

I think my main issue is that I do not have gmap .js files, only .js.coffee files. Am I supposed to convert the coffee script files to js files?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've already spent 4 hours trying to get this to work :[

Comment: you don't have the asset pipeline enabled? well, then you should be sure the gem's js files are included in the view, is it the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the gmaps4rails gem doesn't care whether you have enabled the asset pipeline or not.
Have a look at the generator: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/lib/generators/gmaps4rails/install_generator.rb#L8

A quick fix would be to just copy over the js files manually.

```
mkdir public/javascripts/gmaps4rails
cp `bundle show gmaps4rails`/public/javascripts/gmaps4rails/*.js public/javascripts/gmaps4rails
```

QnD but should get you going :-)

Edit: the same applies for the css files of course

```
cp `bundle show gmaps4rails`/public/stylesheets/gmaps4rails.css public/stylesheets/
```

Comment: Actually, it does care :) https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/lib/gmaps4rails/view_helper.rb#L81